# How to solve the problem of installing Tensorflow2.12.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow

My Python version is 3.10.9, and the TensorFlow version that I'm installing is 2.12.0. Every time I run my code, it shows that my package can't apply to my python. I've tried Chat GPT and every source on the internet, but I still can't solve it. What can I do?

`pip install tensorflow`
and the message:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow-intel 2.12.0 requires keras<2.13,>=2.12.0, but you have keras 2.8.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-intel 2.12.0 requires tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12, but you have tensorboard 2.8.0 which is incompatible.
```

Comment: You may have to update a couple of packages using pip, try upgrading keras to version 2.13 or greater, and do the same for tensorboard.

`pip install --upgrade keras` or `pip install "keras<2.13,>=2.12.0"`
`pip install --upgrade tensorboard` or `pip install "tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12"`

Comment: hey Bro, TF2.X is not available for Python3.10, I will suggest you to install Python 3.7 for best usage of TF

Comment: TF2 works perfectly fine with python 3.10 @EvilReboot . OP, this seems like a problem with older installed versions of tf. Installing keras 2.12 as McRaZick suggested should solve your problem (or there would be another incompatibility issue which will be solved similarly).

Comment: Please provide us some more details like which system OS you are using. Could you please follow the step by step instructions mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to install TensorFlow in your system correctly as per your system OS. Let us know if the issue still persists.